# Using a sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, swap

I was trying to use a sort algorithm according to our programming lecture. Maybe I am just missing something.

I would appreciate it if someone may help me out or could give me a hint about any mistake I made.

Here my current code:

```
package Sortieralgorithmus;

public class sort {

public static int[] straightSelection(int[] numbers) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        int smallestIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            if (numbers[i] < numbers[smallestIndex]) {
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
        }
        swap(j, i, numbers);


    }

    return numbers;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: 1) What's the problem? 2) Use Java code conventions to make your code easier to read; packages are lowercase, classes start with a capital letter.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have `swap` defined anywhere? You have mixed up `i`, `j`, and `smallestIndex` in two places.

Comment: i think you need to do `swap(j, smallestIndex, numbers)`. your condition in the secend loop seems rong because if i runs until the length so i+1 will reach it somewhen and you will get outOfBoundExeption

Comment: @DevSE Dominik Please see my updated answer. Was it what you needed?

Comment: I am sorry for missing information. I always get the error that j cannot be resolved to a variable. I copied the code from lecture paper because I wanted to understand it correctly. I am also sorry for wrong code declarations.

Comment: In said lecture paper, where is the declaration of `j`? (If it is in the same place, make that "sad".) Pay attention to the scopes of variables and identifiers.

Comment: well the code I have posted is the same in the lecture paper there is no specific declaration of j nor of the swap command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an **in-place selection sort**. 
Change

```
if (numbers[i] < numbers[smallestIndex])
```

to

```
if (numbers[j] < numbers[smallestIndex])
```

Also change

```
(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
```

to

```
(int i = 0; i < numbers.length()-1; i++)
```

Additionally, because i and j are declared within your `for` condition, **they are only accessible within the scope of the for loop**. Instead, declare them outside of your loops.

Lastly, it's a good idea to check `if(smallestIndex != i)` before swapping them.

**So here's your working code**, assuming your swap function works correctly.

```
package Sortieralgorithmus;

public class sort {

public static int[] straightSelection(int[] numbers) {
int i, j;  // declare them here 
int smallestIndex; //declare it here as well

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++) {
    smallestIndex = i;

    for (j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
        if (numbers[j] < numbers[smallestIndex]) {
            smallestIndex = j;
        }
    }
    if(smallestIndex != i){
    swap(smallestIndex, i, numbers);
    }

}

return numbers;
}
}
```

Please refer to the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: so it seems like it's working but as I run it I get an empty console and why do I need an Object to retrieve the method straightSelection? Because if I try to retrieve it without one it says : "The method straightSelection(int[]) is undefined for the type Workflow"

Comment: oh sorry it says this: "The static method straightSelection(int[]) from the type Sort should be accessed in a static way"

Comment: @DevSEDominik  removing the static modifier should fix that problem, then.

Comment: I did all I get was this : "[I@15db9742"

Comment: http://collabedit.com/bb899    Okay copy and paste your code there and I will take a look. @DevSEDominik

Comment: http://collabedit.com/bb899 there you go, sorry it took so long. I am in the chat room right now so I will be able to send you the rest of the code

Comment: I see what the problem is. It's not with the algorithm itself, but with the way you are printing it. Let's go back to collabedit bb899. @DevSEDominik

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of the swap command (sorry for wrong declarations I have recognized them and I will change them immediately!):

```
package Sortieralgorithmus;

public class Swap {

public static void swap(int a, int b, int []numbers) {

    int temp = numbers[a];
    numbers[a] = numbers[b];
    numbers[b] = temp;

}
```

}

Comment: Never, ever, choose `public` visibility for something Java without a [doc comment] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html). (Writing the documentation for `swap()`, you should note a shortcoming with the parameter names, esp. with `a` and `b`.)